# Javascript function counter add up despite declaring new var every time

Tags: javascript, function, counter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

    <p id="demo">0</p>
    <p id="try">try</p>

    <script>
    var add = (function () {
        var counter = 0;
        document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = counter;
        return function () {return counter += 1;}
    })();

    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to ask a question. There is a button on the page that when I click, there is a counter that add 1.

But the add() function make a new var counter = 0; every time I call

And document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = counter; is always 0

The counter now add up 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 ....

I don't understand why it doesn't stay at 1 since the counter is always new and equal to 0 everytime I call the function. Thanks!

Comment: You can try a global counter variable

Comment: No, I want to understand this code. This is from w3schools tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Calling add() will not execute the
var counter = 0;
line.

That line only gets executed once according to your code (when declaring the add variable).

You should see this if you test with breakpoints.

Your add function has access to the same counter variable indefinitely since the counter variable was created in the same scope as the add function was defined (function () {return counter += 1;}).

Comment: Why not?

but var counter = 0;  is inside the add() function

When did the  var counter = 0;  execute then? Thanks!

Comment: The var counter = 0 line is actually in the anonymous function that contains the add function definition. The counter variable is declared once when executing the var add = (function () { line

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). So your `add` variable is what you are returning from the IIFE.
So, now your `var add` becomes

```
var add = function () {return counter += 1;}
```

Where `counter` retains it's previous value because of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

And thus on your first click `counter` is 1, then 2, then 3 and so on.